# Quartz ClassNotFoundException for SimpleThreadPool

Tags: java, java-8, quartz-scheduler, guice, dropwizard

I'm trying to configure a quartz scheduler that will only run on one node (https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs#using-dropwizard-jobs-in-a-clustered-environment). Whenever I setup the quartz threadpool, it tells me that `SimpleThreadPool` cannot be found, even though it's loaded in my project via `spinscale/dropwizard-jobs`. The version loaded in is `quartz-2.2.3`

I'm using https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs to integrate quartz into a dropwizard project. I'm using dropwizard 1.0.5, dropwizard-guicey 4.0.1 (https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey), spinscale quartz implementation 3.0.0.

I've hooked up dependency injection via this example here: https://github.com/xvik/dropwizard-guicey-examples/tree/master/dropwizard-jobs

And I've added the following file to my project
`quartz.properties`

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName: "scheduler"
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId: "AUTO"
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck: "true"
org.quartz.threadPool.class: "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: "10"
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: "5"
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: "60000"
org.quartz.jobStore.class: "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX"
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass: "org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate"
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties: "false"
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource: "myDS"
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix: "QRTZ_"
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: "true"
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver: "org.postgresql.Driver"
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz"
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user: user
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password: pass
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections: "5"
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery: "select 1"
```

This is the exception I'm seeing

```
ERROR [2018-03-12 04:38:29,755] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Unable to start server, shutting down
! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"
! at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
! at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
! at org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.loadClass(InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper.java:72)
! at org.quartz.simpl.CascadingClassLoadHelper.loadClass(CascadingClassLoadHelper.java:114)
! at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:822)
! ... 17 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.quartz.SchedulerException: ThreadPool class '"org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"' could not be instantiated.
! at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:824)
! at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1525)
! at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1541)
! at de.spinscale.dropwizard.jobs.JobManager.start(JobManager.java:50)
! at io.dropwizard.lifecycle.JettyManaged.doStart(JettyManaged.java:27)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:411)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:378)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:53)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
! at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
! at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Example in documentation](https://github.com/spinscale/dropwizard-jobs#using-dropwizard-jobs-in-a-clustered-environment) use yaml format, but, as you using pure properties format, you shouldn't wrap values in quotes.

So in your case, it indeed can't find class `"org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool"` because of the quotes.

I would suggest to use main dropwizard config (yaml) for quartz configuration (as library doc suggest) just to keep all configs in one place.